# Get selected object from jQuery Autocomplete

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

I'm using [jQuery 1.8 Autocomplete](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/API/1.8/Autocomplete).

Is there any way of getting the selected object outside of one of the event handlers?

I'm trying to do something like...

```
 $("#searchUsers").autocomplete({
        source: 'Users/List',
  });

  $("#addUser").click(function() {
       // get the selected user Id
       var item = $("#searchUsers").autocomplete('selected');
       alert(item.Id);
  });
```

I can't see any way of doing it but it seems a pretty obvious requirement.

Comment: Wouldn't `$("#searchUsers").val()` give what you want?

Comment: No, I want the object not the value.

Answer (score 1):

I was running to the same problem. I could get access to the selected item as an object.

```
$("#searchUsers").data("autocomplete").selectedItem
```

Answer (score 0):

The default behavior is that when the item is selected, the value is placed in the text box.  So you could get it by just doing `$("#searchUsers").val()`.

If you need more information from the selected item, then you need to pass a `select` event handler, and within that handler, store the information elsewhere.

Comment: That's what I'm doing at the moment but it's hacky and a little buggy. I was hoping there would be a cleaner way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

add the `select` event to your autocomplete function:

```
search: function (event, ui) {
        $("#searchUsers").val('');
    },
select: function (event, ui) {
   foo = ui.item.label;
    $("#bar").val(ui.item.id);
   baz = (ui.item.JsonField);
}
```

look at the Events tab [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete)

**edit:**
added the `search` event to the function. I'm using the `search` event to clear fields/variables every time the user beings a search

Comment: As the question, I don't want an event.

Comment: why not? since that's what does what you need it to

Comment: Because I have to store the variable somewhere, and then also attach a change event to clear the variable since select only updates when a genuine value is selected. I asked the question specifically because I want to *avoid* having to do that, and normally jQuery is well thought out enough to provide some mechanism to handle these kinds of things for you.

Comment: no because the search event only fires after `minLength` and `delay` conditions are satisfied. If you want to do it using events you have to use `change` as described in my previous comment. Your update shows exactly how this type of approach leads to bugs, and why the library really should provide a simple mechanism for doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but still...

Just define a JavaScript variable, and, in select event, set the **object** to that variable. For example:

```
$(function () {
    var object_selected= -1;
    $("#q").autocomplete({
            source: "path/to/jsondata",
            minLength: 3,
            select: function (event, ui) { //This is the event that you need to implement
                $('#q').val(ui.item.value);
                object_selected = ui.item; //This is what you will use later.
                return true;
            }
    });
});
```